# how do I use window.open with self Property

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code on a webpage:

```
<div onclick = window.open('/BuyProd_sku_008.aspx')>
    <uc1:ProductBox runat="server" ID="ProductBox_1" '''ProductImage="/ProductPhotos/Prod_sku_008.png" Description="My description" ImageAltText="My alt text" Price="$6.99"/>'''
</div>
```

I want to include the `self` property but when I include it the new page does not open.

I have tried per W3C Schools:

```
<div onclick = window.open('/BuyProd_sku_008.aspx', self)></div>
```

I have tried `self` and `_self` but neither worked. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `<div onclick="window.open('/BuyProd_sku_008.aspx', '_self')">`